Getting "553 RElaying disallowed as @" when sending mails vor msmtp with cron
I have setup msmtp on my server to send mails via zoho. For this I have configured an explicit from address (from@sender.com for this example)  in my msmtp config:
defaults


account default
auth on
from from@sender.com
host smtp.zoho.eu
logfile ~/.msmtp.log
passwordeval cat /secrets/smtp_password.txt
port 587
tls on

This is of course nessary, because zoho would only accept mails with this from address.
And when using it on the command line it works perfectly:
echo -e "subject: test\n\nhello" | msmtp -- my@email.com

The logs shows that it works, and I get my mail:
Sep 25 09:01:55 host=smtp.zoho.eu tls=on auth=on user=user from=from@sender.com recipients=my@mail.com mailsize=164 smtpstatus=250 smtpmsg='250 Message received' exitcode=EX_OK

But when I configure a crontab:
MAILTO=my@mail.com
MAILFROM=from@sender.com
0 * * * * myuser echo 'not working' && exit 1

I get his in my msmtp log:
Sep 25 09:00:38 host=smtp.zoho.eu tls=on auth=on user=user from=from@sender.com recipients=my@mail.com smtpstatus=553 smtpmsg='553 Relaying disallowed as @' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE

I find this strange, the from is correct in the log message, but the error means that I set an incorrect from, or does it not?
Is cron setting from in another way that I cannot see in the logs?
Can I change this?
